# Added time layer doesn't show

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-web-appbuilder, widget

I'm adding a layer with time control through the widget "add Data"

[image: screenshot]

But this layer doesn't show in map. Could someone give me a clue as to why this happens?

Comment: Are you able to post a link to the layer in question?

Comment: No, sorry. But I had tested the service in other app, and the widget adds the layer without problem.